# windows 10 is not loading after installing ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-10

I am a complete New to Ubuntu. I had Windows 10. I dual booted it with Ubuntu 14.04 . I got Ubuntu 14 installed. When I re-started, on boot menu when I select Windows 10, It dose n't boot. A black screen comes for 2 seconds and again the boot menu comes to grub menu. But when Ubuntu is selected it runs smoothly. what should i do ?? any help..?

Comment: If Windows has been installed in UEFI mode does it boot normally if selected as first priority? How exactly have you prepared for the dual-boot? Please edit the question and describe what you did. Additional you may want to comment about your release choice, i.e., why 14.04 instead of a newer one?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu open a terminal and run `sudo os-prober` then `sudo update-grub` and finally reboot. If that doesn't resolve your issue you will want to boot Windows installation media in UEFI mode provided that Windows has been installed in UEFI not legacy mode then select **repair your computer**, **troubleshoot** and finally **startup repair**

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and in most of the cases it's because the grub can't find windows partition. First, you should try to install Grub customizer and check if windows figures in the list, then run this command to add it if it doesn't exists : `sudo update-grub`.

If that didn't do the trick, you should try boot-repair and follow the instructions given in the official site. Hope that will help.